# Embedding Xamarin Forms in Native Xamarin app with MvvmCross 6.0

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to embed Forms XAML view into Xamarin Native application with MvvmCross 6.0.

I tried to reproduce effect of [this solution](https://github.com/munkii/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Forms/NativeToXF) but I got stuck on registering `IMvxFormsViewPresenter`. I also followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/native-forms).

I have simple `MainContainerActivity` with `MainFragment` (with corresponding `MainViewModel` in Core) that contains a button to Forms `SettingsActivity`/`SettingsViewModel`.

Full source can be found in the [test repository](https://github.com/orestesgaolin/MvvmCrossForms2Native/tree/develop/src).

Currently, I struggle with an exception thrown in `base.OnCreate(bundle);` while navigating to `SettingsViewModel`:

> MvvmCross.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException has been thrown
>
> Failed to resolve type MvvmCross.Forms.Presenters.IMvxFormsViewPresenter

I cannot find a way to register this Forms Presenter. I tried to do it in `Setup` but with no success.

I also tried to resolve `MvxFormsAndroidViewPresenter` in `SplashActivity` but `Mvx.Resolve<IMvxViewPresenter>() as MvxFormsAndroidViewPresenter;` yields null.

Do you have any idea what should I do to incorporate Forms views into MvvmCross 6.0 native application?

```cs
namespace MvvmCrossFormsEmbedding.Droid.Views
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/AppTheme",
              Label = "SettingsActivity")]
    public class SettingsActivity : MvxFormsAppCompatActivity<SettingsViewModel>
    {
        public static SettingsActivity Instance { get; private set; }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            // #1 Initialize
            Forms.Init(this, null);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_settings);
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.layout_toolbar);
            SupportActionBar.Title = "Settings";
            Instance = this;

            // #2 Use it
            var frag = new SettingsView().CreateFragment(this);

            var ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_frame_layout, frag, "main");
            ft.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Have same use case, existing MvvmCross 6.0 application where I want to incorporate some Xamarin.Forms views.

Comment: @Cheesebaron , any clues?